# Accessing IFrame elment from external page loaded inside iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, iframe

I would like access the IFrame element available in the main page from the IFrame source page using JavaScript

Here is my main Page

```
<html>
<body>
<IFrame id="page-container" src="http://stackoverflow.com"
      width="200px" height="200px">
</IFrame>
</body>
</html>
```

Child Page

```
 <html>
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"/>
   <script type="text/javascript" >
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var containerFrame= $('#page-container');
    //var containerFrame=document.frames["page-container"];
    //var containerFrame=document.frames["page-container"];
    //var containerFrame=document.parent.frames["page-container"];
   });
   </script>

   <body>
   <div>some content..</div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

I am getting **undefined** for all my tries.

***How it can be done? Is it possible?***

> **Edit**: I ***tried loading a cross domain page***.
>
> In IE i am getting error ' for security reason framing is not allowed' and also
>   domains, protocols and port must match. Can we achieve this any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var containerFrame = $('#page-container', window.parent.document)
```

This should firstly reference the parent of the window and then look for the iframe div

Comment: I tried loading cross domain page. But getting an error. Is it possible? Please see my updated answer

Comment: No sorry, browsers do not let iframes with different domains call each others functions, its a security thing

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the context to search for `#page-container` in, which in this case will be the parent window.

```
var containerFrame = $('#page-container', window.parent.document);
```

Comment: @Murali no problem, glad to help. Don't forget to accept an answer. Go for jye265's as he got his in first :)

Comment: I immediately started trying accepting answer, but SOF says me 'You can accept an answer in 6 minutes'. Just waiting :)

Comment: I tried loading cross domain page. But getting an error. Is it possible? Please see my updated answer